Finding a vector that maximize orthogonality from a set of given vectors
As for the title, I am looking for a unit vector that is the most possible orthogonal to a set of given vectors. I explain how I set the problem mathematically to the best of my ability (I apology for bad notation or ill posing the problem!).
We have a set of $N$ vectors of $D$ dimensions made of real numbers. We call these vectors $\textbf{p}_i$ with $i = 1,...,N$. We consider the vector $\textbf{q}$, again $D$-dimensional and made of real numbers. Moreover, we want that $|\textbf{q}| = 1$, namely, its length is unity.
To my understanding, I have to solve a constrained optimization problem of this form:
$$ \min{ \left( \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \left( \textbf{p}_i^T \textbf{q} \right)^2  +\lambda \left( \textbf{q}^T \textbf{q} -1\right) \right)} \textrm{,}$$
where the square means taking the $L_2$ norm. I can rewrite it in matrix form by calling $P = [\textbf{p}_1, ..., \textbf{p}_n]$, and I would get:
$$ \min_{\textbf{q} \in \mathbb{R}}{ \left( \textbf{q}^T P P^T \textbf{q}  +\lambda \left( \textbf{q}^T \textbf{q} -1\right) \right)} \textrm{.}$$
The original question was: Does this have an analytical solution for $\textbf{q}$? If so, how do I get it?
I think that finding the minimum requires taking the gradient of the argument with respect to $\textbf{q}$ and setting it to zero. If I didn't commit any mistake, this provides:
$$ \left(P P^T + \lambda I \right) \textbf{q} = 0 \textrm{,}$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix. $\textbf{q}$ cannot be zero.
Intuitively, as pointed out in the comments, the answer is that we have to find the minimum eigenvalue of $P P^T$. The $\textbf{q}$ I am looking for should be the eigenvector corresponding to this eigenvalue. Not 100% sure why!

It is not clear to me if $| \boldsymbol{q} |=1$ already or you want $\boldsymbol{q}$ to have a unit norm? if the latter, you may impose it as a constraint.

$|\textbf{q}| = 1$ is something that I want to impose. In principle solving just the left hand side of the minimization problem could lead to $\textbf{q}$ of any magnitude, right? I am trying to imposing it through Lagrange multiplier.

@c'estpasnormale, that sounds like an answer.  Can I encourage you to write in the 'Your Answer' box, so we can upvote it and the question can be treated as answered?  This platform works best when answers are placed into the answer box, not in the comments.  No need to write anything longer or more than you already wrote, that looks perfectly satisfactory as an answer.

@c'estpasnormale, I come to the same conclusion intuitively! I'll add some points to the question. Thanks for the help!
